# Cannot create map from two connected entities in Java

Tags: java, lambda, stream, hashmap, java-stream

I have the following entities (unnecessary parts are omitted for brevity):

```
public class Site {

    private UUID uuid;

    private UUID countryUuid;
}
```

```
public class Country {

    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Currency currency;
}
```

I have `List<UUID>` of `Site` and try to create `Map<UUID, Currency>` for `siteUuid` and `Currency` pair. I have tried something as shown below in order to go by using country list but have not managed.

```
// get site list
final List<SiteDTO> siteList = siteService.findAllByUuidIn(siteUuidList);

// then get country list
final List<CountryDTO> countryList = siteList.stream()
      .map(SiteDTO::getCountry).collect(Collectors.toList());

// then finall try to map them to Currency
final Map<UUID, CountryDTO> uuidCurrencyMap = countryList
      .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(CountryDTO::getUuid, Function.identity()));
```

However, `uuidCurrencyMap` gives `countryUuid` - `Currency` pairs, but I need `siteUuid` - `Currency` pairs. So, is it possible?

Comment: Doesn't `uuidCurrencyMap ` contain countries rather than currencies?

Comment: `uuidCurrencyMap` contains currencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```java
List<SiteDTO> siteList = siteService.findAllByUuidIn(siteUuidList);
Map<UUID, Currency> siteCurrency = siteList.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(SiteDTO::getUuid, siteDTO -> siteDTO.getCountry().getCurrency()));
```

Comment: You are rock!!!